# Set list item default with Ansible

Tags: ansible

With Ansible, is there a way to set a default value for a list item?
For example, if I define a list in my group_vars file like so:

```
list1:
  item1:
    a: 1
  item2:
    a: 2
    b: a2
...
#the list can contain more than two items.
```

Then in some role I want to use it, but if `list1.item1.b` is not set I want it to use a calculated default instead (eg. something like `{{ "a" + list1.item1.a }}`).

I could set use the `default` filter on each task in the role, but I want to set it once for the role and then use it throughout the role.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: If your expecting the value in a jinja2 template, then you can do `{{ value | default('...') }}`. Better description here http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#default

Comment: @cdr yes, but I would have to do that in every location I wanted to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option here is to define a second variable and use that in your tasks:

```
item_b: "{{ list1.item1.b  | default('a' + list1.item1.a) }}"
```

Comment: How would this work when I need to loop through the list in a task?

Comment: It's a hack, but you can do {{ item.item1.b | default(...) }}, then use {{item_b}} in your loop. jinja templates are evaluated lazily, so you can reference with_items' {{item}} in another var before using it in the loop. The other option is a second list that has the defaults you want already.

Comment: I did not realize you could reference "item" outside the context of the loop like that. I'll have to try it. You're right though it does seem like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have role A

```
---
name: execute step 1
copy:
  src="{{list1_item1_a_parameter}}"
  dest="{{list1_item2_b_parameter}}"

name: execute step 2
copy:
  src="{{list1_item1_a_parameter}}"
  dest="{{list1_item2_a_parameter}}"
```

Now, let's take a look how would you call this role

```
---
...
roles:
  - { role: A,
      list1_item1_a_parameter: '{{list1.item1.a.parameter | default("some default") }}' 
      list1_item2_a_parameter: '{{list1.item2.a.parameter | default("some default") }}' 
      list1_item2_b_parameter: '{{list1.item2.a.parameter | default("some default") }}'
    }
```

You can set these defaults at vars/main.yml, inside your role, too.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, it would not work with a loop, or with an arbitrarily long list.

Comment: you are right. but this is the only way to set default values only once for a role.